# Parametrization of a line gamma so that $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{2z}dz $ equals $\pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a contour integral from a proof, somebody there told me it followed from cauchy  integral formula, i know (i probably dont understand it) cauchys integral formula: $$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$$and i dont understand how one can get to this  :

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{2z}dz =\pi i$$

with the help of it. Please do tell me if you see it.

Comment: think about f(z) = 1 and write $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz = 2\pi i$

Comment: for $\gamma$ the unit circle (traversed once, counter-clockwise) we have
$$
\int_{\gamma}dz/z=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=2\pi i
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f = 1$, and $z_0 =0$.  Then $$1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-0} = \frac{1}{\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2z}$$  Thus, $\pi i = \int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{2z} $